# Memcached: How to detect server is not available?

Tags: node.js, memcached

I have a node backend who access to Memcached with the module memcached-promosify. If my application starts and the server of memcached has not been started I can detect if I can get access trying to get the information of a key with the command:

```
cache.get("key");
```

The response is quickly and I get *undefined* in that case. Here, everything works fine.

But, If I start my memcached server with *sudo service memcached service start* and later a stop the server of memcached with *sudo servive memcached service stop* when I try to detect if the server is up with the same comand than before *cache.get("key")* I get an error than before I didn't get.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:11211
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

This error is getting after 1 minute of wating.

How can I detect that the server is up or down quickly?